# Pass a list to Elasticsearch query template

Tags: list, templates, elasticsearch

I am trying to pass a list of parameters to a search query (filter by terms) in Elasticsearch. It works when it's not in a template, just in a query:

```
"terms": {
      "speaker": ["HAMLET", "KING HENRY IV"]
      }
```

I've put it into the template like this:

```
"terms": {
            "{{filter1}}": "{{filter1_val}}"}
        }
```

And then call it like this:

```
GET shakespeare/_search/template
{
  "id":"template",
  "params": {
    "filter1": "speaker",
    "filter_value1": ["HAMLET", "KING HENRY IV"]
  }
}
```

And I get the following error:

```
{
  "error": {
    "root_cause": [
      {
        "type": "parsing_exception",
        "reason": "[terms] query does not support [speaker]",
        "line": 1,
        "col": 98
      }
    ],
    "type": "parsing_exception",
    "reason": "[terms] query does not support [speaker]",
    "line": 1,
    "col": 98
  },
  "status": 400
}
```

I have tried adding brackets to the template itself like  "{{filter1}}": [{{filter1_val}}] and adding quotes and deleting them, and passing a parameters in the form of "[\"HAMLET\", \"KING HENRY IV\"]", but none of this worked.

What am I doing wrong? What is the right way to do this? Any suggestions are welcome.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution here:

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/1.6/search-template.html#_passing_an_array_of_strings

Passing an array of strings

```
GET /_search/template
{
  "template": {
    "query": {
      "terms": {
        "status": [
          "{{#status}}",
          "{{.}}",
          "{{/status}}"
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  "params": {
    "status": [ "pending", "published" ]
  }
}
```

which is rendered as:

```
{
"query": {
  "terms": {
    "status": [ "pending", "published" ]
  }
}
```